# How to manage memory?

Tags: android

I believe my question deals with memory management.

my program is a matching card game. my layout consists of 12 ImageViews. 
my activity file has a **List ImageView property** that references these 12 ImageViews.
This is done in the `OnCreate` method where i also set a click listener to the ImageViews.

this is an example of the click listener:

```
private void clickImage(View view){

    ImageView imgV = (ImageView) view;
    imgV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ImageView imgV = (ImageView) v;
            new ShowCardImage().execute(Integer.valueOf(imgV.getTag().toString())-1);
        }
    });

}
```

ShowCardImage is an AsyncTask class where once the ImageView is clicked, the appropriate face image will be displayed.

The program works perfectly as is. As i select an imageview depicting a cover image, it is replaced with a face image.

Now i need to compare every 2 cards that are selected. How do i go about this?
I am automatically thinking of a **List Integer property** to represent the tags of the ImageViews.

Now for the comparing of 2 cards, should i create another AsyncTask class.
And if so where should it be called, in the listener after the ShowCardImage execution. Or Should i call it in the ShowCardImage class. if so, where, in the `doinbackground()` or the `onpostexecute()`.

And also, is my current code good for memory management? From my understanding, everytime an image is clicked a task is performed in background.

So lets say if the user presses on card1 five times. Does that mean 5 separate background tasks are created at the same time. 5 items of the same tag for the List property that keeps track of cards the user selected.

Can this be avoided by making sure to program the image's setEnabled to false, when i change the image in ShowCardImage class's `onProgressUpdate()`?

Or do i have to check that items one and two of the **List Integer property** are the same in the beginning of `doinbackground`. If so, what is to prevent tasks 3, 4, 5, adding card1 tag when i am removing it during task 2.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get my program to work. To compare selected cards I created an AsyncTask class titled **DoCardsMatch**. I execute this in my **ShowCardImage** AsyncTask in the onPostExecute method

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if(selectCards.size() == 2)
            new DoCardsMatch().execute();
    }
```

I also managed to set a score.
I created a List to keep track of each card individual points.
each card starts with 20 points. In the DoCardsMatch class if the cards don't match, I subtract 5 points from the selected cards associated location in the points List. If they do match, I execute another AsyncTask class in the DoCardsMatch onPostExecute method to set the score.

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //code written here
        if(//cards match)
                  adjustScore = true;
         else //cards don't match
            adjustScore = false;
            }        
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        if(adjustScore){
            Integer cardPts1 = cardPoints.get(loc.get(0));
            Integer cardPts2 = cardPoints.get(loc.get(1));
            SetScore score = new SetScore();
            score.setScore(false);
            score.execute(cardPts1 + cardPts2);
        }

    }
```

I think i am managing memory alright. I have added a new game button.

When the program starts 7.65 MB of memory is allocated.

After playing 3 games, the memory allocated is now 8.88 MB.

But when I press the Initiate GC button in the android monitor. It goes down to 8.13 MB.

Next i press the new game button, I now press the Initiate GC button again, it goes down to 7.38 MB.